# Creating a Trigger with ExecuteSqlCommand() Throws "Incorrect syntax near the word 'TRIGGER'."

Tags: c#, entity-framework, triggers, dbcontext

This seems like I'm missing a simple detail, I just can't figure out what.

Having this

```
string deleteTrigger =
            "IF OBJECT_ID('@p0') IS NOT NULL " +
            "DROP TRIGGER [@p1] ";
string createTrigger = 
            "CREATE TRIGGER [@p0] " +
            "ON [dbo].[@p1] " +
            "AFTER DELETE AS " +
            "BEGIN " +
                "SET NoCount ON " +
                "DELETE FROM [dbo].[MyTable] WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM DELETED) " +
            "END ";

object[] parameterList = new object[] {"Tr_SomeTable_AD", "Tr_SomeTable_AD" };
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(deleteTrigger,parameterList); // Works
parameterList = new object[] { "Tr_SomeTable_AD", "SomeTable" };
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(createTrigger, parameterList); // Exception thrown here!
```

in my `InitializeDatabase(DbContext)` throws an exception:

> SqlException: Incorrect syntax near the word 'TRIGGER'

on the second `ExecuteSqlCommand` (the first one works fine). I've also tried

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(createTrigger, "Tr_SomeTable_AD", "SomeTable");
```

instead of using an `object[]`, but the result is the same.

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21973627/executesqlcommand-on-seed-to-create-trigger-with-entityframework-throws-sqlexcep), but the answer does not solve my problem. I know the problem must be related to the fact that I'm using parameters, because if I just put the values in the createTrigger string, the SQL command works. However, I'd like to have it parameterized to make it easier to use the same trigger creation code on different tables.

**SOLUTION:**

As said by @marc_s (see answer below), I cannot parametrize table or column (or trigger) names in T-SQL - I'll have to create the complete, final T-SQL statement in C# (using string.Format()). Thus:

```
string deleteTrigger = "..."; // same as before
string createTrigger = 
            "CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[{0}] " + 
            "ON [dbo].[{1}] " + ...

object[] parameterList = new object[] {"Tr_SomeTable_AD", "Tr_SomeTable_AD" };
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(string.Format(deleteTrigger,parameterList)); 
parameterList = new object[] { "Tr_SomeTable_AD", "SomeTable" }; // Use string.Format() here!
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(string.Format(createTrigger, parameterList));
```

does the trick.

Comment: You **cannot** parametrize table or column (or trigger) names in T-SQL - you'll have to create the complete, final T-SQL statement in C# (using `string.Format()`) and then execute that completed T-SQL statement

Comment: You can have method that formats string because in current situation parameter usage is incorrect.

Comment: @marc_s yup: That was it. Feel free to write that as an answer and I'll accept. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **cannot** parametrize table or column (or trigger) names in T-SQL; unfortunately, DDL (Data Definition Language) statements cannot be parametrized.

You will have to create the complete, final T-SQL statement in C# (using `string.Format()`) and then execute that completed T-SQL statement as a whole.